# SSRS Parameters passed through URL not refreshed on Web Part Page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, reporting-services, web-part-page

My working environment is SSRS 2008 and SharePoint 2010.I have a report with parameters running in SP 2010. I call my report page in SP 2010 from a page with all the parameters in query string. On the actual report page all the parameters are set correctly from url the problem is the report doesn't show up until I change anything from the page controls (e.g. change date parameters from date time filter on the page). I want my page to read all the parameters from query string and show the report as the page loads without any user intervention.How this can be done?

Your suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

You can define the parameters normally in report builder but when you pass the parameters from query string you need to append it with rp:

`http://sitename.com/_layouts/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/Reports/MyReport.rdl&rv:ParamMode=Hidden&rp:city=Perth`

where Relative report url is the url to your .rdl file (Report file)

Have a look at this link for more info http://akurniaga.wordpress.com/2012/07/24/url-access-to-ssrs-with-parameters/

Comment: Well I am trying to view my report on a web part page rather than on Report server default url. But anyways thanks for your inputs. I resolved my issue its not related to SP 2010.

Comment: How did you resolve the issue? I am also facing same problem. I have placed the web part in the Pages library's page but not able to filter using query string parameter.